# Building packages with conda and python3k

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

So I'm building a package with conda on Win7:

```
conda skeleton pypi $pkgname
conda build $pkgname
binstar upload ./conda-bld/win-64/$pkgname-py27_0.tar.bz2
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/myname $pkgname
```

With python2k, this works like a charm. However, using python3k this fails because the `patch` package is not available for python3k. Error (example for `docopt`):

```
$ conda skeleton pypi docopt
Using url https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/docopt/docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 KB) for docopt.
Downloading docopt (use --no-download to skip this step)
Using cached download
Unpacking docopt...
done
working in C:\cygwin64\tmp\tmpy7erx8vyconda_skeleton_docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Applying patch: 'C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\tmpy7erx8vyconda_skeleton_docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz\\pypi-distutils.patch'
Error:
    Did not find 'patch' in: C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\_build\Scripts;C:\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Python\Python3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python\Anaconda3;C:\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\cygwin64\lib\lapack
    You can install 'patch' using apt-get, yum (Linux), Xcode (MacOSX), or conda, cygwin (Windows)
```

When trying to install `patch`:

```
$conda search ^patch$
Fetching package metadata: ....
patch                        1.12.11                  py27_0  defaults
```

No `patch` package for python3k - does this mean no package building for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same recipe that you built with Python 2. Or you can create an environment with `patch` (`conda create -n patch patch`) and put it on your `PATH`. Or you can install patch from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm.

Comment: You're totally right, that was silly of me. Installed patch with cygwin installer, worked fine. Thank you!